# Typescript definition function to get instance based on parameter class?

Tags: typescript, definition

1. A base class.

```
class A {}
```

2. B, C extends A

```
class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}
```

3. Use function to create instance.

```
namespace D {
  function NewInstance<T extends A = A>(iclass: T): T;
}
```

Want: remove `<T extends A>` and auto determine the return type based on the input class.

`D.NewInstance(B) => B`, `D.NewInstance(C) => C`

Currently: If I do not set the generic, `D.NewInstance(B) => A`, `D.NewInstance(C) => A`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the default type in generic function declaration should make things work as you are expecting.

```
interface A { }
interface B extends A { }

function NewInstance<T extends A>(iclass: T): T { 
  return iclass
}

const a: A = {}
const b: B = {}

NewInstance(a) // return A
NewInstance(b) // return B
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Karthick Vinod, But my function's parameter is a class.

Answering my own question. The key is util type `type Newable<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;`

```
abstract class A {
  a: number = 1;

  abstract aa(): void;
}

class B extends A {
  bb: number = 2;

  aa(): void {}
}

class C extends A {
  cc: number = 3;

  aa(): void {}
}

type Newable<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function NewInstance<T extends A>(iclass: Newable<T>): T {
  return new iclass();
}

const a = NewInstance(A); // error, A is not newable

const b = NewInstance(B); // return B
console.log(b.a); // ok
console.log(b.bb); // ok
b.aa(); // ok

const c = NewInstance(C);
console.log(c.a);
console.log(c.cc);
c.aa();
```